# Lock screen wallpaper without audio playing in background iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, background, wallpaper, lockscreen

I am working on application in which i have to change the lock screen wallpaper without playing audio in background through application programmatically. I have done with audio in background but is there any way i can do through application. There is an app on appstore here is the link https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sticky-notes-hd-with-bump/id364874025?mt=8 I dont know how it is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to do that. The app you linked generates images and stickes them in the user's camera roll. The user still has to manually update her wallpaper to the most recenktly generated image.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply but are you sure about it ,do you have this application in your device downloaded.

Comment: I'm positive about it. It is not possible on a standard , non-jailbroken device. I don't have this app, but they say in the app description how it works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.It helps me a lot.